# API Usage Notifications - How to subscribe not via UI, e.g. using API, ant deployment etc

Tags: metadata-api, limits, tooling-api, notification

When spinning up new sandbox from production we need to subscribe our admin user to receive 'API Usage Notifications'. So in order not to do it manually every time, we are looking for a way of how to automate it. But so far cannot find anything related to this neither in Metadata nor in Tooling API.

Can someone point at Metadata object or whatever which is responsible for this? 
Any help would be appreciated.

This only idea we have for now is just to use tools like Selenium or puppeteer to automate clicking via browser - but not a big fun of that idea.

Below is the screen from Setup area which seems to be the only way how we can subscribe to this notifications.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I can see the name "MonitoringRateLimitingNotification" in the url in that setup page, but don't see that listed in any documented API for salesforce. Also based on the prefix "076" in that same setup url, I found the name of "RateLimitingNotification" but, again, no mention of that in any documentation.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no way you can do this programmatically in sandboxes. This need to be a manual post refresh step.